# in tcl with sqlite binding, "eval" command didn't do anything for "ATTACH DATABASE"

Tags: linux, sqlite, tcl, redhat

I am trying to perform database connection automatically using tcl since its what was recommended for sqlite

I tried "eval" for CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO, and SELECT FROM. They all worked as expected, but it didn't work with ATTACH DATABASE.
The following script did not do anything

```
#!/user/bin/tclsh
load /usr/lib/sqlite3.20.1/libsqlite3.20.1.so Sqlite3

sqlite3 main_db /location1/dbfile.sqlite
main_db eval { 
 ATTACH DATABASE "/home/location2/dbfile2.sqlite3" AS db; 
}
```

After execution I did not see the database attached

Thanks!

Comment: How did you determine the database was not attached? Any error messages to help us along?

Comment: After the execution of the script I opened up the sqlite3 console on dbfile on location 1. Then I typed the .databases only "main" and "temp" showed up, "db" was not present.

Comment: And also thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the SQLite docs implies that attaching to a database only gives you the ability to refer to that database in the same session by prefixing table names with the attached database name. I don't think "attachment" implies any modifications to the original database file. So, starting another process to view the effect of attaching is not going to show anything. Perhaps there is some other way to solve the problem you thought attaching would solve.

Comment: You are correct sir!
It did work, the way I checked it is wrong.
I went ahead and assumed it worked, added the usual next steps, and the results are as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It actually worked as expected, the way I checked it was wrong.

As andy mango pointed out, the state of database attachment is per session, meaning:

Running sqlite3 on location1/dbfile on the console is one session.
Running the tcl script on location2/dbfile2 is a separate session.

The ATTACH DATABASE was executed on tcl session. I checked the status of attachment on the console session and nothing showed up, so it appeared that the script didn't work.

But it worked none the less and this is what I did:

```
#!/user/bin/tclsh
load /usr/lib/sqlite3.20.1/libsqlite3.20.1.so Sqlite3

sqlite3 main_db /location1/dbfile.sqlite
main_db eval { ATTACH DATABASE "/home/location2/dbfile2.sqlite3" AS db } 
main_db eval { INSERT INTO log VALUES(1, 'timetamp', 'event', 'remark')} # log is the table that already exists in location2/dbfile2
maindb close
```

I verified that it worked by opening a session on the console for location2/dbfile2, the added data was there.

The idea is using tcl script open a session on location1/dbfile, then attach location2/dbfile2 to that session, so that the session connected to location1/dbfile can manipulate location2/dbfile2.

The intent was for using TRIGGER to establish an auditing trial for the location1/dbfile, but the log needed to be in a different location.